# Get email items from mailboxes through powershell

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0, powershell-4.0

I need to retrieve email items from outlook from various mailboxes.
I found the below script that works fine for my inbox. But how do i define other mailbox name in the script.
I have many mailboxes and each hour i need to retrieve items from the mailboxes, hence looking out for automation which help save efforts.

```
 Function Get-OutlookInBox 
{ 
  <# 
   .Synopsis 
    This function returns InBox items from default Outlook profile 
   .Description 
    This function returns InBox items from default Outlook profile. It 
    uses the Outlook interop assembly to use the olFolderInBox enumeration. 
    It creates a custom object consisting of Subject, ReceivedTime, Importance, 
    SenderName for each InBox item.  
    *** Important *** depending on the size of your InBox items this function 
    may take several minutes to gather your InBox items. If you anticipate  
    doing multiple analysis of the data, you should consider storing the  
    results into a variable, and using that.  
   .Example 
    Get-OutlookInbox |  
    where { $_.ReceivedTime -gt [datetime]"5/5/11" -AND $_.ReceivedTime -lt ` 
    [datetime]"5/10/11" } | sort importance  
    Displays Subject, ReceivedTime, Importance, SenderName for all InBox items that 
    are in InBox between 5/5/11 and 5/10/11 and sorts by importance of the email. 
   .Example 
    Get-OutlookInbox | Group-Object -Property SenderName | sort-Object Count  
    Displays Count, SenderName and grouping information for all InBox items. The most 
    frequently used contacts appear at bottom of list.  
   .Example 
    $InBox = Get-OutlookInbox 
    Stores Outlook InBox items into the $InBox variable for further 
    "offline" processing. 
   .Example 
    ($InBox | Measure-Object).count 
    Displays the number of messages in InBox Items 
   .Example 
    $InBox | where { $_.subject -match '2011 Scripting Games' } |  
     sort ReceivedTime -Descending | select subject, ReceivedTime -last 5  
    Uses $InBox variable (previously created) and searches subject field 
    for the string '2011 Scripting Games' it then sorts by the date InBox. 
    This sort is descending which puts the oldest messages at bottom of list. 
    The Select-Object cmdlet is then used to choose only the subject and ReceivedTime 
    properties and then only the last five messages are displayed. These last 
    five messages are the five oldest messages that meet the string.  
   .Notes 
    NAME:  Get-OutlookInbox 
    AUTHOR: ed wilson, msft 
    LASTEDIT: 05/13/2011 08:36:42 
    KEYWORDS: Microsoft Outlook, Office 
    HSG: HSG-05-26-2011 
   .Link 
     Http://www.ScriptingGuys.com/blog 
 #Requires -Version 2.0 
 #> 
 Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null 
 $olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]  
 $outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application 
 $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
 $folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInBox) 
 $folder.items |  
 Select-Object -Property Subject, ReceivedTime, Importance, SenderName 
} #end function Get-OutlookInbox
```

Comment: Assuming you are using an Exchange Server (or Office365) : you should try to use the EWS API for these kinds of tasks. It supports impersonation and it's much more reliable then the Outlook COM Object. Glen Scales has written a lot of articles on his blog about using EWS (http://gsexdev.blogspot.nl/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could try adding a param block to your script so you can run something like "Get-OutlookInbox -Mailbox ". It would look something like this:

```
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
     ValueFromPipeline=$true,
     Position=1)]
    [string[]]$Mailbox=$env::USERNAME
)
```

So just to break it down a little, the actual name of the parameter is "Mailbox" and it is set to a default value that returns the current user running the script. You can override it by specifying one when you run the function. This will also accept a value from pipeline, meaning you can have an array of strings called "$aliases" and then run it like this: $aliases | Get-OutlookInbox

Comment: Thanks Joseph, I tried adding the Param to my function but it throws error.

Comment: i have added it this way and i m trying to run the script                             
Function Get-OutlookInBox 
{               
      param (
        [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,
   ValueFromPipeline=$true
         Position=1)]
        [string[]]$Mailbox=$env::USERNAME
    )
 Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null 
 ..................

Comment: I made a correction to my answer. I forgot to put a comma after "ValueFromPipeline=$true" that I saw in your comment.

Comment: Yes it worked now :) thanks a lot..But how do i call the function?.. I tried it like>>>>>> PS I:\> mailbox1,mailbox2 | Get-OutlookInbox

Comment: It runs but still gives output from my primary mailbox, not the other ones which i input

Comment: Seems like that would work. You could try 

$aliases = "alias1","alias2"
$aliases | Get-OutlookInbox

Or you could try:
Get-OutlookInbox -Mailbox $aliases

Comment: You could also try removing "=$env::USERNAME" altogether

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144664/discussion-between-ruchi-and-joseph).

Comment: tried with this too..i am getting emails from my inbox..
param ( 
[Parameter(Mandatory=$true, 
ValueFromPipeline=$true, 
Position=1)] 
[string[]] 
) 
Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null 
$olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type] 
$outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application 
$namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
$folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInBox) 
$folder.items | 
Select-Object -Property Subject, ReceivedTime, Importance, SenderName 
} #end function Get-OutlookInbox

Comment: My guess is that it has to do with using COM object. It probably cannot connect to a remote computer then? Which makes me think you should use the EWS API mentioned by the other guy (whatever that means, lol).

Comment: Here's a thought. Log in to the computer as another user that has a mailbox and a profile in Outlook and run the script again.

Comment: I don't think that should be an issue, because the mailbox are configured on my machine itself...I believe that should happen with this script only..please say yes :(

Comment: Yeah, the more I think about it, I'm sure it has to do with using COM objects. You are connecting to Outlook, not Exchange. If you want to get various mailboxes, you should connect to Exchange and not Outlook.

Comment: I had a confusion, I have a macro that fetches the email items through all the mailboxes , if macro does this, should powershell also do this without exchange server, just a query to u..

Comment: I don't think Powershell uses macros at all. You might be able to execute a macro in Powershell though.

Comment: You got me wrong, I have a macro that does this job of getting mailbox items from different mailboxes through outlook itself, hence i thought powershell should also fetch it without getting connected to exchange server.

Comment: This is no answer to the question. The submitter asks for getting different mailboxes.