# Get email addresses from all Folders of my mailbox through powershell

Tags: powershell, outlook, get, export-to-csv, email-client

How to get Email Addresses from All Folders of my mailbox through PowerShell

Thanks to following URL, please find code for InBox
[https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44068261/get-email-items-from-mailboxes-through-powershell](https://www.stackoverflow.com/)

I change following line to include Email Address
`Select-Object -Property Subject, ReceivedTime, Importance, SenderName, SenderEmailAddress`

**but need help to get All Folders**

```
 Function Get-OutlookInBox 
{ 
  <# 
   .Synopsis 
    This function returns InBox items from default Outlook profile 
   .Description 
    This function returns InBox items from default Outlook profile. It 
    uses the Outlook interop assembly to use the olFolderInBox enumeration. 
    It creates a custom object consisting of Subject, ReceivedTime, Importance, 
    SenderName for each InBox item.  
    *** Important *** depending on the size of your InBox items this function 
    may take several minutes to gather your InBox items. If you anticipate  
    doing multiple analysis of the data, you should consider storing the  
    results into a variable, and using that.  
   .Example 
    Get-OutlookInbox |  
    where { $_.ReceivedTime -gt [datetime]"5/5/11" -AND $_.ReceivedTime -lt ` 
    [datetime]"5/10/11" } | sort importance  
    Displays Subject, ReceivedTime, Importance, SenderName for all InBox items that 
    are in InBox between 5/5/11 and 5/10/11 and sorts by importance of the email. 
   .Example 
    Get-OutlookInbox | Group-Object -Property SenderName | sort-Object Count  
    Displays Count, SenderName and grouping information for all InBox items. The most 
    frequently used contacts appear at bottom of list.  
   .Example 
    $InBox = Get-OutlookInbox 
    Stores Outlook InBox items into the $InBox variable for further 
    "offline" processing. 
   .Example 
    ($InBox | Measure-Object).count 
    Displays the number of messages in InBox Items 
   .Example 
    $InBox | where { $_.subject -match '2011 Scripting Games' } |  
     sort ReceivedTime -Descending | select subject, ReceivedTime -last 5  
    Uses $InBox variable (previously created) and searches subject field 
    for the string '2011 Scripting Games' it then sorts by the date InBox. 
    This sort is descending which puts the oldest messages at bottom of list. 
    The Select-Object cmdlet is then used to choose only the subject and ReceivedTime 
    properties and then only the last five messages are displayed. These last 
    five messages are the five oldest messages that meet the string.  
   .Notes 
    NAME:  Get-OutlookInbox 
    AUTHOR: ed wilson, msft 
    LASTEDIT: 05/13/2011 08:36:42 
    KEYWORDS: Microsoft Outlook, Office 
    HSG: HSG-05-26-2011 
   .Link 
     Http://www.ScriptingGuys.com/blog 
 #Requires -Version 2.0 
 #> 
 Add-type -assembly "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook" | out-null 
 $olFolders = "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.olDefaultFolders" -as [type]  
 $outlook = new-object -comobject outlook.application 
 $namespace = $outlook.GetNameSpace("MAPI") 
 $folder = $namespace.getDefaultFolder($olFolders::olFolderInBox) 
 $folder.items |  
 Select-Object -Property Subject, ReceivedTime, Importance, SenderName, SenderEmailAddress 
} #end function Get-OutlookInbox
```

I got help on InBox but need help to get all folders

Answer (score 0):

Syntax for Get-MailboxFolder follow [This link for more abou](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/exchange/get-mailboxfolder?view=exchange-ps)

```
Get-MailboxFolder
   [[-Identity] <MailboxFolderIdParameter>]
   [-Recurse]
   [-DomainController <Fqdn>]
   [-MailFolderOnly]
   [-ResultSize <Unlimited>]
   [<CommonParameters>]
```

Try this code apply your fields.

```
   $DomainSuffix = Read-Host "Type the domain name suffix that you look for"
# Creating folder structure and file names for the exported CSV files
$A20 = "C:\INFO\E-mail address\Exchange Online\E-mail address with Domain suffix - $Domainsuffix"

if (!(Test-Path -path $A20))
{New-Item $A20 -type directory}


# Exchange Online infrastructure
# Define the variable for the different type of Exchange Online recipients

$AllRecipients = Get-Recipient -ResultSize unlimited| Where {$_.EmailAddresses -like "*@$DomainSuffix"}
$SoftDeleted = Get-Mailbox -SoftDeletedMailbox | Where {$_.EmailAddresses -like "*@$DomainSuffix"}
$UnifiedGroups = Get-UnifiedGroup | Where {$_.EmailAddresses -like "*@$DomainSuffix"}
if ($SoftDeleted -eq $null)
{
write-host "There are no Soft Deleted Exchange Online mailboxes that have an E-mail address with the domain name suffix - $DomainSuffix"
}
else
{
$SoftDeleted | Select DisplayName,EmailAddresses,RecipientType,RecipientTypeDetails | Export-CSV $A20\"Exchange Online Soft Deleted mailboxes that their E-mail address include the domain name suffix $DomainSuffix.CSV" –NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8
}
if ($UnifiedGroups -eq $null)
{
write-host "There are no Exchange Online unified groups that have an E-mail address with the domain name suffix - $DomainSuffix"
}
Else
{
$UnifiedGroups | Select DisplayName,EmailAddresses,RecipientType,RecipientTypeDetails | Export-CSV $A20\"Exchange Online unified groups that their E-mail address include the domain name suffix $DomainSuffix.CSV" –NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8
}
if ($AllRecipients -eq $null)
{
write-host "There are no Exchange Online Recipients that have an E-mail address with the domain name suffix - $DomainSuffix"
}
Else
{
$AllRecipients | Select DisplayName,EmailAddresses,RecipientType,RecipientTypeDetails | Export-CSV $A20\"Exchange Online recipients that their E-mail address include the domain name suffix $DomainSuffix.CSV" –NoTypeInformation -Encoding utf8
}
```

for reference follow this [Site](https://o365info.com/searching-email-addresses-with-a-specific-domain-name-suffix-using-powershell-office-365-part-10-13/)